# excel - autofill incrementing multiple numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if it is at all possible to use Excel's autofill features to increment more than one number in a cell when dragged.  The example lines below are each in a cell.  For example, I have

```
sometext 234 othertext 898
```

in a cell.  When I drag the fill handle down I get the following in the cells below:

```
sometext 234 othertext 899
sometext 234 othertext 900
```

...etc.  What I *want* to get is:

```
sometext 235 othertext 899
sometext 236 othertext 900
```

...etc.  Right now I'm hacking it together by putting 234 and 898 in separate columns, filling those down so they increment, and then using something like this in the first actual cell:

```
=CONCATENATE("sometext ",A1," othertext ",B1)
```

so that it will fill to

```
=CONCATENATE("sometext ",A2," othertext ",B2)
```

...etc. when I drag the fill handle down.  I'd really like to not have to do this, though, so I was hoping there was some loop I could jump through to make it happen easily.

Using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells in the column with the data cell at the top of the selection and blank cells below it.  Then run this macro:

```
Sub DrawDown()
    v = Split(Selection(1), " ")
    For i = 2 To Selection.Count
        v(1) = v(1) + 1
        v(3) = v(3) + 1
        Selection(i).Value = Join(v, " ")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it works beautifully.  I was hoping to avoid macros, but this is pretty short and elegant.

Comment: Sometimes macros give you just the functionality you need.......why not use them??

Answer (score -1):

What are you using this for?
If you dont NEED excel,
Use Notepad++

Column Editor will do what you need.

Comment: I've never used that particular functionality in Notepad++, but it sounds nice.  Unfortunately, it doesn't help me anyway - I don't have access to it.  I have very little control over the computer in question and it has heavy restrictions on new software.

Comment: I would suggest that you request to have Notepad++ reviewed and approved for use by your IT. Very powerful tool for programming.
To me, it sounded like you do not really want to write much code at all. I honestly think, if you do not have access to other tools with this functionality and you do not want to write much code, then the way you have been doing it in excel would be the *quickest & easiest*, otherwise, writing a macro would definitely be a valid avenue

Comment: I might do that.  All my actual programming is done almost entirely on Linux systems, and this Excel functionality is only really desired for some of my record-keeping.  However, additional, more code-oriented tools for Windows can't hurt.